# bootstrap grid align 2 divs in one row one in the page center other to the right

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have one flex container that has 2 divs, I want the first aligned horizontally in the center of the container and the second to the right, using only bootstrap.

|---------------------------------------------|

```
              center
               div1            div2
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what you're asking. Please provide some code, or an example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have one flex container that has 2 divs, I want the first aligned horizontaly in the center of the container and the secont to the right, using only bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with bootstrap only using 2 child `div` elements.  What you can do is create a placeholder `div` with no content and give it a `col` class equal to the right side `div`.  This will push your content to the center while using only bootstrap.

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/boots>trap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex text-center">
  <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    I have some Content
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    I also have more content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I the only thing I did different was instead of creating the the empty div I used the offset class 

<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">